# Sum every 7 columns in PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with this covid data set provided by usafacts below. Each column represent a single date with the header in format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

[Source](https://static.usafacts.org/public/data/covid-19/covid_confirmed_usafacts.csv)

I would like to display the data in terms of weeks, starting with Monday and ending with Sunday.

Here is my approach:

1. Drop all the day columns so that I have Monday at the beginning and Sunday at the end. Done.
2. Perform a sum for every seven days (columns) to form data for the weeks. Not sure how to do this step.
3. Since the data is cumulative, calculate the difference from one week to another go get the new weekly cases.

Any feedback on the approach would be appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE 1:
I think it would be wise, to calculate the difference between all the day columns first, before summing them into weeks. Is there a pyspark equivalence of `.diff()` from pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach makes sense, except that if you keep Mondays and Sundays and use their difference to get the number of cases per week, you are missing what happens between Sundays and Mondays. You are just considering 6 days and not seven. You need to compute the difference between each Monday for instance and the previous one.

One way to go at it is to:

1. Only keep Mondays (drop the other columns)
2. Compute the differences between each consecutive Mondays
3. Optionally explode the dataset (one line per week) so that it is easier to use and so that you have a stable schema even if more weeks are added to the dataset. But the first 2 steps may be enough for you.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
import datetime

# A function that tells if a date is a monday
def is_monday(date):
    [year, month, day] = date.split("-")
    return datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day)).weekday() == 0

# reading the data
covid = (
    spark.read
         .option("header", true)
         .option("inferSchema", true)
         .csv("covid_confirmed_usafacts.csv")
)

dates = covid.columns[4:]
mondays = [ d for d in dates if is_monday(d) ]
cols = covid.columns[0:4]

# for each monday, we compute the difference with the previous one.
# For the first monday, we compute the diff with the first date we have.
# You may remove that first part if you don't need it.
diffs = (
    [f.col(mondays[0]) - f.col(dates[0])] +
    [f.col(mondays[d]) - f.col(mondays[d-1]) for d in range(1, len(mondays))]
)
# simply naming the week column with by its monday 
named_diffs = [ diffs[d].alias(mondays[d]) for d in range(len(mondays)) ]
result_1 = covid.select(cols + named_diffs)

# Step 3: exploding the dataframe
result_2 = covid\
    .withColumn("s", f.explode(f.array(*structs)))\
    .drop(*dates)\
    .select(cols + ['s.*'])

result_2.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- countyFIPS: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- County Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- State: string (nullable = true)
 |-- StateFIPS: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = false)
 |-- value: integer (nullable = true)
```